# Why have I a different result using Pool Multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have this function that returns a dictionary with the elements of a list named, as seen here:

```
lista =['GILDIKNK','MENIA']
dic={}

def nome_arquivos(lista_fragmentos):
    for elemento in lista_fragmentos:
        indice = "fragmento_" + str(lista_fragmentos.index(elemento)+1)
        dic[indice] = elemento
    print(dic)

nome_arquivos(lista)
```

The output, in this case, is (and is what I want):

```
{'fragmento_1': 'GILDIKNK', 'fragmento_2': 'MENIA'}
```

However, I'm trying to insert multiprocessing, for bigger problems. This is my code:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time

lista =['GILDIKNK','MENIA']
dic={}

def nome_arquivos(lista_fragmentos):
    for elemento in lista_fragmentos:
        indice = "fragmento_" + str(lista_fragmentos.index(elemento)+1)
        dic[indice] = elemento
    print(dic)

def pool_handler():
    pool = ThreadPool(4)
    results = pool.map(nome_arquivos, lista)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_handler()
```

The output is:

```
{'fragmento_1': 'G', 'fragmento_2': 'I', 'fragmento_3': 'L', 'fragmento_4': 'D',
'fragmento_6': 'K', 'fragmento_7': 'N'}{'fragmento_1': 'M', 'fragmento_2': 'E',
'fragmento_3': 'N', 'fragmento_4': 'I', 'fragmento_6': 'K', 'fragmento_7': 'N',
'fragmento_5': 'A'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you map the list you pass strings to the function which are also iterable, so you get no errors, but  each letter is used on the for loop. BTW, it make no sense to use the same original function for the multiprocessing code. I believe you want to just put the code inside the for loop

Comment: The `ThreadPool.map` function accepts an iterable, which it maps a call to the function for each value.  So each of the strings is passed to the function as an argument.  Is there a specific reason you're using a linear search (`index`) to find the index of a string in a list you're creating?

Comment: @Jason The `index` was the way I found to create the keys in the dictionary according to each list element.

Comment: @BrunoSantos You're searching a list in linear time for every call to your function so you're complexity is `O(n^2)`.  Using multiprocessing won't solve an inefficient algorithm.

Comment: Having your function modify a global variable is risky, and as far as I can tell, completely avoidable here.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your comments, and I want to add one thing that I have observed on stackoverflow: questions use to be done by newbies in programming, but I always think twice before make questions here because there is this depreciation that regular programmers do with the questions. This is particularly discouraging.

Comment: @BrunoSantos Was that in response to my comment? If I came off as harsh, I’m sorry, that wasn’t my intention at all. I will edit my answer tomorrow to try to actually explain the reasoning behind my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

There are already some good comments on why your code doesn’t work, so I thought I would try rewriting your first function (the one without any multiprocessing). It should be efficient enough on its own, I would be surprised if multiprocessing were to ever become necessary.

```py
def proc_names(names_lst):
    return {f'fragmento_{idx}': curr_name for idx, curr_name in enumerate(names_lst, start=1)}
```